# UIButton cancel my scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have `UITableView` with `customCell`

inside the cell I have buttons.. whats happens is that when I scroll down the buttons was very sensitive so I add the lines:

```
self._tableView.canCancelContentTouches = YES; 

self._tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

and its start to work fine beside one thing, in facebook app when u press a button hold.. then scroll its start to scroll.. how they done it?
whats happens in my case is that when u hold a button and scroll its not scrolling but cancel the button action..

Answer (score 0):

They've done it by having delaysContentTouches set to YES. What do you mean by "the buttons were very sensitive", which you tried to fix by setting it to NO?